# If a redirect is setup on a webserver, does all traffic continue through the webserver with the redirect?

Tags: web-server, redirect

If we have a redirect setup on a web server inside our company.  Does all traffic continue to go through the webserver with the redirect as sort of a middle man?  Or does the redirect occur only with the initial request and all subsequent traffic go straight from client to the second server.

Here is a picture to explain what Im trying to ask.  I think Option A is how it works, but I'd like verification on my hunch.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a redirect sends an HTTP 30x response code to the client, which tells it a new location to make a request to (directly).

The scenario where the first server acts as the go-between is proxying, which can be achieved in most web server software as well.